# XCode Widget Label Line Break

Tags: xcode, text, widget, label, line

i have a Problem with my iOS widget. in my widget i have a label wich i fill with the text from a url.
the text contains a "\n" and the label should display a line break.also i have set the number of lines to 0.
here is my code:

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/*myname*/Desktop/test.txt"]];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
label.text = string;
```

but the label displays the \n as if it was a normal character and not a line break

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In a string is \r a line break.